# PortfolioAnalytics [R] - optimize.portfolio.rebalancing error

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory, portfolio-optimization, asset-allocation, rebalancing

New to using PortfolioAnalytics (and fairly new to R in general) and am encountering an error when running `optimize.portfolio.rebalance` -- see below:

*Error in UseMethod("extractObjectiveMeasures") : 
  no applicable method for 'extractObjectiveMeasures' applied to an object of class "c('simpleError', 'error', 'condition')"*

I've looked at the vignette and package documentation on CRAN, but haven't been able to figure out what might be causing this specific problem. `optimize.portfolio` seems to work fine with the same constraints and objectives. Perhaps I haven't loaded all of the required libraries? Open to any other suggestions. Thank you.

```
# Load packages
library(xts)
library(ROI)
library(doParallel)
library(PortfolioAnalytics)

# Define pseudo dates and returns (format as xts)
dates <- seq(from = as.Date("2016-01-01"), to = as.Date("2016-12-01"), by = "month")
returns <- as.xts(data.frame("A" = runif(12, -.05, .05), 
                         "B" = runif(12, -.10, .20), 
                         "C" = runif(12, -.15, .30)), 
                  order.by = dates)

# Register doParalell session (PortfolioAnalytics suggests this when running optimizations w/ rebals)
registerDoParallel(cores = 2)

# Initiate portfolio object
port <- portfolio.spec(assets = colnames(returns))

# Add constraints 
port <- add.constraint(portfolio = port, type = "long_only")
port <- add.constraint(portfolio = port, type = "full_investment")
port <- add.constraint(portfolio = port, type = "box", min = 0.02, max = 0.40)

# Add objectives - want to maximize Sharpe Ratio
port <- add.objective(portfolio = port, type = "risk", name = "StdDev")
port <- add.objective(portfolio = port, type = "return", name = "mean")

# Run optimization WITHOUT rebalancing - THIS SEEMS TO RUN FINE...
portOPT <- optimize.portfolio(R = returns,
                              portfolio = port,
                              optimize_method = "ROI",
                              maxSR = TRUE)
portOPT

# Run optimization with rebalancing
portOPT.R <- optimize.portfolio.rebalancing(R = returns,
                                            portfolio = port,
                                            optimize_method = "ROI",
                                            maxSR = TRUE,
                                            training_period = 6,
                                            rebalance_on = "months")
portOPT.R
```

**EDIT**

Also, I'm running Windows 10 and thought it would be helpful to include a list of my currently installed packages:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JLauyCpmDg3DOztRJKntoZ2LFMxV4_ouLOKYUVenEAA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Tried running your code. Getting a strange error related to ROI package...

Comment: Thanks. Neglected to load the ROI package--it is loaded now in the post. Should correctly display the error I referenced now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 0.2 versions of the ROI packages made breaking changes. We're working on a fix. In the meantime, I would suggest downgrading to ROI v0.1-0 and and ROI.plugin.* to 0.0-2.

You could also run the optimization with a different optimization method, e.g. `optimize_method = "random"` or `optimize_method = "DEoptim"`.

Comment: Thanks RossB. Reverting to the older versions of ROI and its plugins seemed to solve the issue. Thanks again.